# how to use JavaScriptSerializer on certain properties of a child class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class B that inherits from class A.

```
Class B:A
{
   public string Prop1{get;set}
   public string Prop2{get;set}
   public string Prop3{get;set}
}
```

I would like to serialize (json) certain properties in class B say prop1 and prop2 and none in class A. 
I am using JavaScriptSerializer and this serializes A and B.
I tried setting Recursion limit to 1 but that throws an error. I am not allowed to edit class A

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define a DTO class in this case:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

then use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map from a `B` instance to `Foo`. Finally I would JSON serialize the `Foo` instance that was returned by `AutoMapper`. This way I have total control over what gets serialized.

Another possibility is to use an anonymous object:

```
B b = ...
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new 
{ 
    b.Prop1, b.Prop2 
});
```

or if you wanted to rename those properties in the resulting JSON:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new 
{ 
    Foo = b.Prop1, 
    Bar = b.Prop2 
});
```